# Управление клавиатурой на Си

Tags: linux, c

подскажите пожалуйста, пишу программу на С под Ubuntu и мне нужна моя программа для автоматического нажатия нужной клавиши клавиатуры.

Если показать пример на питоне, то он выглядит так:

```
import pyautogui as pag
import webbrowser
import time


pag.typewrite('for example')
pag.press('enter')
```

но мне нужно сделать это на C.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1262310/6944845